# Change URLs in PHP through .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am asking question after so many attempts to do this. Found many results on this website but none of them worked for me.

I have a website built in PHP (no any CMS) that has URLS like

```
www.someweb.com/job_detail.php?job_id=123456789
```

I just want to convert all URLS like these

```
www.someweb.com/123456789
```

Here is my .htaccess content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RedirectMatch 404 ^/admin/$
RedirectMatch 404 ^/admin/uploads/$
ErrorDocument 404 /page_not_found.php
<Files index.php>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from all
</Files>
```

Please tell me how to do this? I think I need to do some change in just .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /job_detail.php?job_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: This is better since it takes into account occasional trailing slash. You may want to omit / before job_detail.php though.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^([0-9]+)$" "job_detail.php?job_id=$1" [L]
```